# Count word characters in selected rows/cells

Tags: vba, ms-word, character, cell

I have to count characters in word selections that have tables. I found the following VBA code:

```
Sub CountCharacters()
    Dim Title As String
    Dim CharCount As Integer
    Dim Message As String

    Title = "CharCount"
    CharCount = Len(Selection)
    Message = LTrim(Str(CharCount)) + " character"
    If CharCount <> 1 Then Message = Message + "s"
    MsgBox Message, vbOKOnly, Title
End Sub
```

The trouble is that it counts the characters of just one selected cell.
How to change it to count characters in other cells as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub CountCharacters()
    Dim Title As String
    Dim CharCount As Integer
    Dim Message As String

    Title = "CharCount"

    'To select the table in which the cursor is place.
    'NOTE: if the cursor is not in a table is will give an error
    Selection.Tables(1).Select

    CharCount = Selection.Range.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticCharacters)

    Message = LTrim(Str(CharCount)) + " character"
    If CharCount <> 1 Then Message = Message + "s"
    MsgBox Message, vbOKOnly, Title


    'Otherwise you can use:
        'Note that the "Cell End Markers" are seen as two chracters Chr(13) & Chr(7).
        'You will then need to subtract the  number of cells multiplied by 2.
        'You also need to take into account that those cell end markers are in _
            each line outside the table as well.
        'There is also a Selection.Tables(1).Range.Cells.Count but this will omit _
            the additional "Column" of cell end markers
        CharCount = Len(Selection) - (Selection.Tables(1).Rows.Count * _
                                     (Selection.Tables(1).Columns.Count + 1)) * 2

    Message = LTrim(Str(CharCount)) + " character"
    If CharCount <> 1 Then Message = Message + "s"
    MsgBox Message, vbOKOnly, Title

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! The explanation is also very helpful.

Comment: @LeFunk, just remember to mark the answer as correct and give it a up vote. Enjoy Stackoverflow